# Determinar tempo de voar do personagem no Unity

Tags: c#, unity-5

Preciso que ele execute o comando de voar por um certo período.

> Exemplo: O personagem possui uma jetpack, se apertar a tecla "espaço"
>   duas vezes ele vai ativar o código de voar, só que o astronauta só
>   poderá voar por 5 segundos e logo depois parar de voar.

Este é o código

```
 if (canFly && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            //Voando
            GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("flying", true);
            rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(rigidbody.velocity.x,+2.5f);
        }
        else
        {
            GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("flying", false);
        }
```

Comment: Não seria só você registrar o momento em que o jogador pressionou o a tecla de espaço e ver se já passou os 5s?

Comment: Eu não sei como é pega as teclas no Unity mas imagino que seja algo assim: No evento 'OnKeyDown' se for espaço inicia um timer para 5s. No evento 'OnKeyUp' se for espaço cancela o timer. No evento 'OnTimer'  inicia o vôo e se auto-cancela.